# SSIS Derived column giving error on CAST function

Tags: ssis

I am trying to use `(DT_DATE) DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE())` in a derived column. However, by the time I can start writing my expression with `(DT_DATE)` it turns red and shows an error. Whether it's just `(DT_DATE)` sitting there or the full expression it throws an error.

Here is a screen shot of the error [image: Error Report]

Also:

- If I remove this one derived column expression the rest of my package works fine, including a different derived column
- All I'm doing is taking an Excel file, adding two derived columns to it, then putting into an SQL database

Basically it seems to not want to accept `(DT_DATE)`. I'm sure I'm making some small error here but I've tried everything I can think of and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If theres any additional information I can provide to help someone answer please let me know. Anyone know what the error codes mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the expression you are showing in your question as evidenced by the error message.

> Attempt to parse the expression "(DT_DATE)DATEADD(DAY,-1GETDATE())"
>   failed and returned an error

Your expression with problems is the one for `Batch_as_of_Date`

```
(DT_DATE)DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())
```

If you don't put double quotes around the first argument SSIS tries to parse it as a column. Since you don't have a `DAY` column in your input columns so you get this error message:

> Attempt to find the input column named "DAY" failed ....

So your expression would need to be

```
DATEADD("Day", -1, GETDATE())
```

This is clearly documented in [DATEADD (SSIS Expression)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141719.aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much Tom. Im used to SQL where DATEADD does not use quotes. Gonna check the expression more carefully in the future.